# Hey , I am trying to make a bot info command, can anyone help me on how to make the information specific to the bot? I'm using pycord

Tags: python, server, discord, bots, pycord

I have a code on how to get user info, but I want to change it from member to bot, here is my code for user info:

```
@client.command()
async def bot(ctx, module=None):
    if module == None:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Bot Information:", timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, color=discord.Color.random())
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author}!")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/939979247190167623/f6c97d2970da016e2dbb9bfa52d6d9f3.png?size=4096")
        embed.add_field(name="Bot Created On:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))
        embed.add_field(name="Joined This Server On:", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))
        embed.add_field(name="ID:", value=member.id)
        embed.add_field(name="Server Display Name:", value=member.display_name)
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
    elif module == "info":
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Bot Information:", timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, color=discord.Color.random())
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author}!")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/939979247190167623/f6c97d2970da016e2dbb9bfa52d6d9f3.png?size=4096")
        embed.add_field(name="Bot Created On:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))
        embed.add_field(name="Joined This Server On:", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"))
        embed.add_field(name="ID:", value=member.id)
        embed.add_field(name="Server Display Name:", value=member.display_name)
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```

I also want to add stuff like how much ram it has and how many members and servers it is in/has.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot) and [Guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild) for bot and guild attributes.

Here is a command you can use to print the guilds your bot is in on the console and some info about the guilds you can also put the information in an embed like you did with the users if you'd like:

```
    @bot.command()
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def servers(ctx):
        print(f'Logged in as: {bot.user.name}\n')
        print(f'Server List ({len(bot.guilds)})\n')
        server_counter = 1
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            print(f"{server_counter}. {guild.name}, owned by {guild.owner} with {guild.member_count} members")
            server_counter += 1
```